# How to remove .aspx from the URL in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, redirect

How to remove .aspx from the URL in IIS?
I need this one for SEO purpose, If any one have a idea then please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried searching in google for this

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to Rewrite URLS. I have not done it personally so can't provide any samples. But there are tonnes of examples available on the web.

Here is a quick example I found: [ASP.NET rewriting URLs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the System.Web.Routing RouteCollection. You set a series of rules when your application starts (i.e. call from global.asax Application_Start). You can map extensionless URLs to actual pages in your site, and process the url parameters in your page.

In global.asax: -

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

.
.
.

```
RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;

// simple route that maps /index to /index.aspx
routes.MapPageRoute("home", "index", "~/index.aspx");

// more complex route that handles parameters
routes.MapPageRoute("products-category",
                    "products/{main-category}/{category}",
                    "~/pages/product-landing.aspx");
```

To process URL parameters in your page (second example): -

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

.
.
.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string mainCategory = string.Empty,
               subCategory  = string.Empty;

        if (RouteData.Values["main-category"] != null)
        {
            mainCategory = RouteData.Values["main-category"].ToString();
        }

        if (RouteData.Values["category"] != null)
        {
            subCategory = RouteData.Values["category"].ToString();
        }

        // and then do what you need to with those parameters..
```

So in this example, if someone requests `http://yoursite.com/products/animals/monkeys/` then your `main-category` will be *animals* and `category` will be *monkeys*.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way of achieving it. Add it to handlers section of web.config

```
<add
    name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"
    path="*."
    verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
    modules="IsapiModule"
    scriptProcessor="%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
    preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" 
    responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add
    name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
    path="*." 
    verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
    modules="IsapiModule"   
    scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
    preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
    responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add 
    name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" 
    path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" 
    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```